# Как менять версии скриптов при сборке React приложения чтобы у пользователя при обновление приложения не кэшировались скрипты css

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При сборке приложения необходимо менять версии скриптов и css например с src='/script.js?v=1' на src='/script.js?v=2' то же самое для css подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если используется `create-react-app`, то там вебпак все сам делает.

Comment: Нет не делает почему то